# How do I try to convert in this SQL case

Tags: sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am studying SQL Server right now, and after doing a tutorial,
then found the Oracle query source and tried to convert it to SQL Server, but I'm having trouble reproducing the function.

How can I convert to SQL Server using >WITH or >CASE?

**Oracle Query**:

```
SELECT D.*,LEVEL - 1 AS MENU_LVL
          ,DECODE(CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF, 0, 'N', 'Y') as IS_LEAF,'' AS ROLE_ID, 
CASE WHEN EXISTS 
             (SELECT 1
                    FROM TB_SY_ROLE_MENU A
                         ,TB_SY_MENU B
                    WHERE A.COMP_CD = B.COMP_CD
                      AND A.MENU_ID = B.MENU_ID
                      AND A.ROLE_ID = #{ROLE_ID}
                      AND D.COMPCD = A.COMP_CD
                      AND D.MENU_ID = A.MENU_ID) 
                    THEN
                       1
                    ELSE
                       0
              END AS CHECK_YN
      FROM (SELECT A.COMP_CD COMPCD
                  ,A.MENU_ID
                  ,A.MENU_NM
                  ,A.P_COMP_CD
                  ,A.P_MENU_ID
                  ,A.MENU_SORT
                  ,A.USE_CD
                  ,A.WINDOW_COMP_CD
                  ,A.WINDOW_ID
                  ,NVL((SELECT USER_NM
                      FROM TB_SY_USER X
                      WHERE X.USER_ID = A.LAST_MDFR_ID),LAST_MDFR_ID) LAST_MDFR_NM
                  ,A.LAST_MDFC_DTM LAST_MDFC_DTM
              FROM TB_SY_MENU A
             WHERE A.USE_CD = 'Y'
               AND A.COMP_CD = #{COMPCD}) D
     START WITH D.COMPCD = #{COMPCD}
            AND D.MENU_ID = 'ROOT'
     NOCYCLE PRIOR D.COMPCD = D.COMPCD
           AND PRIOR D.MENU_ID = D.P_MENU_ID
     ORDER SIBLINGS BY D.MENU_SORT, D.MENU_ID
```

Comment: This is a recursive query. Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: EVOLVE! No one should be using [old-style joins via the where clause](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Develop GOOD habits. Cryptic alias names are a bad habit as well.